# Drush migrate command not working

Tags: drupal, upgrade, drush

I would like to upgrade Drupal 7 to Drupal 8 using Drush command. I installed Drush and modules of Migrate Tool and Migrate Plus. In command prompt when I enter "drush help" it list out all Migrate Tools commands.
But when I use the command drush migrate-upgrade it returns an error - The drush command 'migrate-upgrade' could not be found.

I refer this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2350651 for upgrade. Please give some guidance to do this upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Migrate Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) module besides of what you have already installed. Then you would be able to execute `drush migrate-upgrade`.

Comment: I already installed and enabled that module and it is required when enable the 'Migrate Tool' module.

Comment: @Senthil In any way, I personally don't recommend using a migration tool. Sometimes it's better to start clean and just migrate specifically what you need. Most Drupal 7 modules are not fully migrated yet or not even in plan to be migrated. For that reason what you would need to do is to copy any CSS and HTML because everything in Drupal 8 is so much different. That's just a personal preference.

Comment: Ok thanks. For now I just need to export all node data of a content type from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. No need to migrate any modules, I just need the node data base (content) to be export from Drupal 7 and import in Drupal 8. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: This link is more useful - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185364/upgrading-from-drupal-7-to-8-with-drupal-upgrade-a-bug